# "Error: expression must have a pointer type" when using the "this" keyword

Tags: c++, this

So I made a parent class, which i will call `Parent` that has a `Square*` grid member variable. The grid variable is a pointer to a large array of Squares, which contain `key` member variables. (Think of this project as a hashtable) The problem is I am making a function in the `Parent` class that edits the key variables in the `Square` array, and getting an error. This line of code compiles:

```
this->grid = new Square[row*col];
```

but this line does not compile:

```
this->grid[i*col + j]->key1 = j;
```

it underlines `this` and says expression must have a pointer type. I was wondering if anyone had ideas to what i may be doing wrong?

```
void Parent::initialize(int row,int col) {
    this->grid = new Square[row*col];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < col; j++) {
            this->grid[i*col + j]->key1 = j;
            this->grid[i*col + j]->key2 = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: erase redundant 'this->' from your code; it is not Javascript.

Answer (score 16):

You have to use

```
this->grid[i*col + j].key1
this->grid[i*col + j].key2
```

That is because even if it is true that your grid is a pointer, you have allocated in the are pointed by its memory an array of `Square` object. So when you use the [] operator you are obtaining an object of type `Square` and not a `Square*` and for a `Square` object you hve to use the *. operator* and not the *-> operator.*

Comment: I came back too late, I already replaced the -> with . already, but thank you for your help! I feel like a fool for such a simple problem

Comment: No problem, it happens :) However if it solved the problem accept on of the answers (mine or the one from the other guy) to close the question and for future reference :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

I guess `this->grid` is of type  `Square*`, so `this->grid[0]` is of type `Square&` and you must use `.` (dot) not `->` (arrow) to access members from `Square&`. To use arrow for expression **expression must have a pointer type**...

```
this->grid[i*col + j]->key2
//                   ^^: this->grid[i*col + j] is not a pointer 
this->grid[i*col + j].key2
//                   ^ use dot to access key2 and key1 too
```